# connect mongo database special characters

Tags: database, mongodb

A buggy software i'm using created a mongo database with a special character in its name.

The database name looks like : "database?authSource=Admin"

I would like to connect to this database "database?authSource=Admin", but this special character is wrongly interpreted by MongoClient.

I have tried to use URI encoding and connect to "database%3FauthSource%3DAdmin", but that does not connect me to the right DB.

How can I connect to a mongo database containing special characters ?

Comment: try escape the question mark character with slash/back-slash, as equal symbol as well

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either...
I've solved the problem by fixing the bug on third party software, which gave me a database with a clean name.